# How to generate code manually in authorization code flow in IdentityServer4?

Tags: c#, angular, identityserver4, openid-connect

So basically I have a client app in Angular which currently uses OIDC to communicate with IdentityServer4. Unlogged users get redirected to IdentityServer4 View where they enter username/password, and it redirects them with tokens to my app. That works fine.
Client app however for everything other than authorization uses another API, let's call it MainAPI.
Now my client (person) wants to get rid of the user/password and exchange it for custom token login which should be handled by MainAPI. However, he doesn't want me to strip logic of identity server, and wants angular app to continue using OIDC, but handling everything without IdentityServer4 View.

So what I need is, once I authenticate custom token successfully on MainAPI, call IdentityServer4 to generate tokens/authorization code as if I logged in.
How do I generate authorization code manually? Once I have that code, I should be able to call:

````
{
    Address = IdentityServerPipeline.TokenEndpoint,

    ClientId = "client",
    ClientSecret = "secret",

    Code = code, => how to get code
    RedirectUri = "https://app.com/callback",

    // optional PKCE parameter
    CodeVerifier = "xyz"
});```
````

Answer (score 1):

You can't generate the authorization code manually, because it is generated and given to you (as a client) by the IdentityServer.

It's just a code that you receive that you then can use to (Via the back-channel) retrieve the final tokens.

So there's no point in trying to create your own code.

Comment: Yes, I know. I was wondering if there was any way to get it without using the backchannel. Doesn't matter anymore, I persuaded client into using IS4 as it's meant to be used. Cheers.